# Floating top bar gnome

Tags: gnome-shell, theme, gnome-panel

I would like to make the top bar in gnome floating. I found some tutorials suggesting editing the gnome-shell.css of the current theme.
I edited the file and added the below to the /* Top Bar */

```
border-radius: 9999px;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
```

It doesn't seem to do the job even after reloading the shell or restarting the whole system.
I am using Arch and on the latest Gnome.

An example from one of my themes:

```
/* Top Bar */
#panel {
  background-color: rgba(40,40,40,0.88);
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 1.86em;
  font-feature-settings: "tnum";
  border-radius: 9999px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  transition-duration: 250ms; }
```

What am I missing?